# Create a list of Movies I'd like to watch on Netflix

Tags: netflix, favorites

Instant Q is not available outside US!

This seems very odd, but it seems there is no way to make a list in my Netflix account (Ireland) of movies that I'd like to watch at a later point.

Often I will browse through the movies on netflix and find one's that look interesting, but I don't want to watch them just now.  I thought there would be a way to favorite a movie or mark to watch later, but I can't find it.

I've resorted to creating a [tumblr blog](http://www.tumblr.com/blog/nfwtw233) to store links to movies I find.

Am I missing something really basic, this seems like an obvious feature to be missing?

Some people say to use the 'Instant Queue' but this apparently is only available in the US!

Comment: This is interesting: https://getsatisfaction.com/netflixuk/topics/queue_system_to_store_movies_one_would_like_to_watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ireland there is now a watchlist feature online and also on my AppleTV so that seems  to have finally solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the watchlist feature of [trakt](http://trakt.tv/) to mark movies and television shows that I want to watch.

---

*Original Answer*

This is what your Instant Queue is for: a list of movies you want to watch. Just click the `+ Instant Queue` button for a movie, then see the list at http://movies.netflix.com/Queue.

Comment: For some extraordinary and very bizarre reason Instant Queue is only availble in the US!

Answer (score 1):

What I've been doing is simply click on the 'More Info' link, which you probably do already right?, and simply bookmark the address in a folder - 'NetFlix - Future' is mine. You can go back to it anytime and watch it or not.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to to this outside of the US, so here is what I suggest.. Get a pen, then a piece of paper and write a list of the movies you want to watch.

Comment: Haha, good old paper. Have you considered this option: http://www.iprivacytools.com/ip-address-us/